# System.NullReferenceException When Trying To Load Functions From A DLL File - C#

Tags: c#, dll, add-on, system.reflection

I'm creating an add-on system for a shell I'm developing using C#. I've followed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial). Here is my function to load an add-on:

```
public void loadAppFromDLL(string assemblyFile)
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.Load(assemblyFile);
    Type app = a.GetType("App");
    MethodInfo loadMethod = app.GetMethod("load");
    object appInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(app);
    loadMethod.Invoke(appInstance, null);
}
```

Here is the add-on:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public class App
    {
        public void load()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Application loaded successfully!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I build the add-on, I place it in the same directory as the shell executable and call:

```
LoadExternalApp lea = new LoadExternalApp();
lea.loadAppFromDLL("SampleApp");
```

(LoadExternalApp contains the DLL loading function)

When I was debugging my shell, I noticed that:

1. The app didn't start
2. There was a System.NullReferenceException

What am I not doing right?

Comment: Have you looked into the Managed Extensibility Framework? Microsoft have already written a pretty decent plugin-system for you ;-)

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
Type app = a.GetType("App");
```

is looking for a type with a *namespace-qualified* name of `App`.

Your type is called `App` in a namespace of `App`, so `Assembly.GetType` is returning `null`, and then you're dereferencing it. Instead, you should use:

```
Type app = a.GetType("App.App");
```

However, [you shouldn't give a class the same name as its namespace in the first place](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx). Fix that, so that you end up with something more like:

```
Type app = a.GetType("App.PlugIn");
```

You should still check whether `GetType` (or `GetMethod`) returns null, in order to fail rather more gracefully and with more information.

Additionally, you should start following .NET naming conventions - give methods names in PascalCase. Oh, and you might want to consider a common interface for your add-ins rather than relying on reflection to call methods.